# Laravel 5.4 - Many to Many - Select Form - Database link

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, many-to-many, laravel-5.4

I am practising Laravel and building a blog for Activity holidays.

I have a posts table which describes the holidays, then an activities table which just has the activity name. I have a joins table that links between them. The two tables share a many-to-many relationship. What I am struggling to achieve is that I would like to add 1 or more activities in the to the table using the select form when adding the posts. Currently it is not registering the activities table but creating the posts to my blog.

I would be grateful for any advise and assistance

See my code below:

// App\ActivityController

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Activity;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ActivityController extends Controller
{
    protected $fillable = [
      'activity_name'
    ];

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post')->using('App\activityPost')->withTimestamps();

    }
    public function index(Activity $activity)
    {
      $posts = $activity->posts;
      return view('posts.index', compact('posts'));
    }

    public function edit(Activity $activity)
    {

        $posts = App\Post::get()->pluck('title','body','id')->sortBy('title');
        return view('activities.edit', compact('activities', 'posts'));
    }
    public function update(Request $request, Activity $activity)
    {

        $activity->update($request->all());
        $activity->posts()->sync($request->posts);
        return redirect ('posts/create');
    }
    public function create()
    {

        return view('activities.create');
    }

    public function store()
    {
      $activity = new Activity;
      $activity->activity_name = request('activity_name');
      $activity->save();
      return redirect('activities/create');
    }

    public function show(Activity $activity)
    {
        return view ('activities.activity', ['Activity'=>$activity]);
    }
}


?>
```

// App\PostController

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Post;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class PostController extends Controller
{

    public function __contruct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth')->except(['index', 'show']);
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::latest()->get();

        return view('posts.index', compact('posts'));
    }

    public function show(Post $post)

    {
        return view('posts.show', compact('post'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
      $activities = \App\Activity::pluck('activity_name', 'activity_name');
        return view('posts.create', compact('activities'));


    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate(request(), [
            'title' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required',

        ]);
      Post::create([
        'title' =>request('title'),
        'body' =>request('body'),
        'user_id' => auth()->id()
      ]);



        return redirect('/');
    }
        public function activities()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Activity')->using('App\activityPost');
    }
        public function update(Request $request, Post $post)
    {
        $post->update($request->all());
        $post->activities()->sync($request->activities);
        return redirect('post');
    }



}

?>
```

//App\Post.php

```
<?php
namespace App;

class Post extends Model

{


    public function countries()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Country::class);
    }
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    public function addComment($body)
    {
        $this ->comments()->create(compact('body'));
    }
    public function activities()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Activity');
    }


}
```

?>

// App\Activity.php

```
<?php
namespace App;


class Activity extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'activities';
    protected $fillable = ['activity_name'];

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $activities = Activity::orderBy('activity_name', 'asc')->paginate(10);
        return view('activities.index', ['activities'=>$activities]);
    }
    public function store()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post');
    }


    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'activity_name';
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view ('activities.create');
    }


}


?>
```

// Routes\web.php

```
<?php


Route::get('/', 'PostController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/posts/create', 'PostController@create');
Route::post('/posts', 'PostController@store');
Route::get('/posts/{post}', 'PostController@show');
Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');

Route::get('/about', 'AboutController@index');

Route::get('/logout', 'LoginController@destroy');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::post('posts/{post}/comments', 'CommentController@store');

Route::get('/posts/activities/{activity}', 'ActivityController@index');
Route::resource('activities', 'ActivityController');
Route::get('/activities/create', 'ActivityController@create');
Route::post('/activities', 'ActivityController@store');
Route::get('/activities/{activity}', 'ActivityController@show');
Route::put('/posts/create', 'ActivityController@update');

?>
```

// resources\views\posts.create.blade.php

```
<form method="POST" action="/posts">

{{csrf_field() }}

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="body">Description</label>
    <textarea name="body" id="body" class="form-control" required></textarea>
</div>


<!-- create form with select multiple
convert activity into array -->


<div class="form-group">
  <label for="activities">Select your Activity</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="activities" size="{{$activities->count()}}" required multiple>
    @foreach ($activities as $activity)
    <option value="activities">
      {{$activity}}
    </option>
        @endforeach
  </select>
</div>



<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Publish</button>
</div>

</form>
```

//ActivityPost Table

```
  public function up()
    {
        if(!Schema::hasTable('activity_post')) {
            Schema::create('activity_post', function (Blueprint $table)      {
                $table->integer('activity_id')->unsigned()->index();
                $table->foreign('activity_id')->references('id')->on('activities')->onDelete('cascade');

                $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned()->index();
                $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');

            });
        }
    }
```

//Activity Table

```
  public function up()
    {
        if(!Schema::hasTable('activities')) {
            Schema::create('activities', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('activity_name');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
    }
```

//Posts Table

```
public function up()
{
        if(!Schema::hasTable('posts')){
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: The `store` method in your controller is where your form data is processed.  You are creating your post, but you aren't creating any activities.  You should create the activites and sync them to your post in that method.

Comment: Hi @BizzyBob thank you for your response. I appreciate it. 

From what you have written it seems that I should create the activity /post join and query to show all the activity data?